# How to force webapp2_cached_property to re-evaluate

Tags: python, forms, google-app-engine, caching, webapp2

I know that `webapp2_cached_property` replaces a method with data after the first call for each call to it thereafter, and thus my problems arise.

I have a multilingual site and I am using a form to build some simple select menus. The select menus are data that change language. Obviously if a user changes the language on the system I would like to rebuild the form. However, I don't want to remove the `webapp2_cached_property` as it will then rebuild the form every time the user calls the same url and that will slow down the system. So does anyone know a way to force `webapp2_cached_property` to re-evaluate on demand, e.g. when client changes language. At the moment I have everything else in the selected language but the select data in the default language. Anything down and dirty will do! Ah, yes this only happens on production and not on the dev server...

```
class HomeRequestHandler(BaseHandler):
    """
    Handler to show the home page
    """

    def get(self):
        params = {}
        params['products'] = []
        params['max_searches'] = 1
        params['user_search_count'] = 0

       return self.render_template('index.html', **params)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def form(self):
        import product.product_data.forms as forms
        return forms.ProductForm(self)
```

Ok, I have tried the following but still the language is not changing in production...

Added this to my base handler - it's working!

```
if hasattr(self, 'form'):
        if self.locale != self.oldLocale and hasattr(self, 'form_no_cache'):
            new_form = self.form_no_cache
            kwargs['form'] = new_form()
            logging.info('reset form')
            logging.info(kwargs['form'].product_type())
        else:
            kwargs['form'] = self.form
            logging.info('using cached form')
```

And added this to my home handler

```
def form_no_cache(self):
    import product.product_data.forms as forms
    return forms.ProductForm(self)
```

All this is fine in development and the logs seem correct in development and production...

Any ideas people?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webapp2/d9VfIgp_QIM

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! Don't know why that didn't come up in my Google searches, must have been late ...

Comment: See latest updates above, still have the same problem, but in development server, logging.info(kwargs['form'].product_type()), shows the correct language, but not in production...

Answer (score -1):

ok, couldn't figure this one out, so rewrote the code to build selects in a simple def and pass as a parameter instead of form. Seems to be working. I have my suspicions regarding wtforms though, but it's a pain not knowing, but no time...